# Как организуется поиск в списках хэш-таблицы?

Tags: java, алгоритм, хеширование, структуры-данных, hashcode

К примеру, есть три ключа: "ключ_1", "ключ_2" и "ключ_3" использование которых приводит к коллизии. Допустим, что hashCode("ключ_1"), hashCode("ключ_2") и hashCode("ключ_3") возвращают индекс 12. Элемент массива с индексом 12 будет содержать ссылку на связный список из трех элементов.

То, как происходит добавление и удаление элементов понятно, а как поиск - не совсем.

То есть как по ключу, хэш которого совпадает с другими ключами, можно получить нужный элемент?

Answer (score 2):

При коллизии сравниваются *сами элементы*.

Кстати, списки - не единственный способ разрешения коллизий, есть еще метод открытой адресации, например.

Comment: А как именно сравниваются элементы? Меня пока интересует хэширование цепочками.

Comment: Ну допустим, у вас строки. Каждая имеет свой хэш, в таблице в ячейках хранятся сами строки. Вы видите, что с этим хешем - несколько строк. Значит, просто идем по цепочке с одним и тем же хешем и сравниваем уже не хэши, но строки. В любом случае сравнения хэша недостаточно - даже если цепочки нет: вдруг это какая-то иная строка? Хэш-таблица *гарантирует только* **отсутствие** *элемента в таблице, если с таким хэшем ничего нет*, но не гарантирует наличие. Все равно нужно полное сравнение информации, а не только хэша.

Comment: @PashaKrizskiy методом `equals`